# How do I load a MultiObjectPicker with valid States for a PortfolioItem type eg PortfolioItem/FEATURE

Tags: rally

I would like to load a MultiObjectPicker with valid States for a PortfolioItem type. I have tried with a custom query using TypeDef._refObjectName, but it does not filter the data.

```
  var stateMultiObjectPicker = Ext.create('Rally.ui.picker.MultiObjectPicker', { 
        modelType: 'State',
        storeConfig: {
            fetch: "Name, TypeDef", 
            //customQuery: '(Name = "Done")',                      THIS WORKS       
            customQuery: '(TypeDef._refObjectName = "FEATURE")', // THIS DOES NOT
         },
    }); 
    this.add(stateMultiObjectPicker);
```

Is there another way to do this? Any guidance will be appreciated!
Is there a way to use a store instead of a model in a MultiObjectPicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using:

```
customQuery: '(TypeDef.Name = "FEATURE")'
```